# Is there a working uPnP client/server combo?

Tags: mythtv, upnp

I have videos stored on one machine; I'd like to watch them on another machine. Both are running Ubuntu 10.04 64-bit.

So far I've tried MediaTomb, MythTV, and python-coherence. None of the clients seem to see the servers and I definitely have connectivity between the client and server machines (so it's not a network issue).

Comment: Have you tried gmediaserver or ushare?

Comment: No, but I was hoping for a documented, working configuration.

Comment: I'm seeing lots of suggestions for servers, but no mention of a working client.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a working combination I found:

MediaTomb as the server (package `mediatomb`). I think almost any of the available uPnP servers should work but this is the one that was working when I found a client.

For clients I used Totem (for video) and Rhythmbox (for audio). I had to install and enable plugins for each of these to be used as a client.

The "Coherence DLNA/uPnP Client" plugin for Totem is packaged in `totem-plugins-extra`. Once you have installed and enabled it, uPnP servers are shown *in the sidebar*, a fact that does not appear to be documented and is not easy to discover.

for audio, the "DLNA/uPnP sharing and control support" is packaged in `rhythmbox-plugin-coherence`. Once enabled, a "Shared" category appears on the left hand side (under Playlists) listing the uPnP servers.

Answer (score 2):

If you can cope without using uPnP, I've used SSHFS and VLC Multicasting or Unicasting to achieve the same results.

I used SSHFS by doing the following:

sudo apt-get install sshfs vlc
sshfs user@server/path/to/video_store /local/directory

I then navigate to that directory with VLC and pick the files I want to watch with that.

If you don't have a reliable network link, then you might get some stuttering with this, but it does work.

If you've got a flat network, you might also want to consider using unicasting or multicasting from VLC.

Here's the link to how to stream using VLC:

[RTSP live streaming - Command Line Examples | VideoLAN Wiki](http://wiki.videolan.org/Documentation:Streaming_HowTo/Command_Line_Examples#RTSP_live_streaming)

Alternatively, you can set up multiple "channels" to watch using this howto:

[Streaming HowTo/VLM | VideoLAN Wiki](http://wiki.videolan.org/Documentation:Streaming_HowTo/VLM)

If you need to use uPnP I've had good results streaming to my PS3 using the [PS3 Media Server](http://code.google.com/p/ps3mediaserver/), although it isn't packaged in the Ubuntu repos, it is just a simple Java application that you tell it where all your video files are. It will perform some transcoding if you need that, and will transfer video, photos and music without any issues.

Answer (score 2):

If you would like to browse you videos on your PS3/XBOX and possibly your TV you can use a DNLA enabled server like TwonkyMedia. ( http://blog.gruenewaldt.net/en/software/ubuntu-linux/set-up-twonky-media-server-dlnaupnp-for-playstation-3-ps3-on-ubuntu-linux-for-video-streaming/ )

You can see a comparison between various Media Servers here: http://www.rbgrn.net/content/21-how-to-choose-dlna-media-server-windows-mac-os-x-or-linux

There is a DLNA plugin for Rhythmbox: http://coherence.beebits.net/wiki/RhythmBox

I haven't tried any of this in Ubuntu, but I have TwonkyMedia running on my WD MyBook World Edition with great results.

Answer (score 1):

I've had *ok* results (can crash) with rygel, at least it works with my xbox, no configuration required. Getting my Panasonic G20 to discover it however is turning out to be a lost cause, I just might give up and fudge a USB gadget to create a pseudo hard drive and attach that to the TV.

Can anyone comment on what the *dominant* DNLA project for Linux is? I want to contribute bug fixes but not to a dead end. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

My recommendation for a DLNA enabled media client/server system is Plex.

http://www.plexapp.com/

It's gone closed source as they are obviously trying to make some money out of it now but it's as close to flawless as I've found.